# Arduino triggers a camera to start recording

Tags: arduino, wireless

I've already made an Arduino device which detects the trigger event, but now I want it to trigger the recording and storage of video when this event occurs.  If the camera could be wirelessly triggered a few feet away from the Arduino unit, that would be optimal, but I can settle for running wires if need be.

I'm looking for suggestions because I'm on a limited budget for this project. I want to avoid reinventing the wheel and ordering parts which I can't get to work with an Arduino.

I'm considering the use of this camera.
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11418

This is my first Arduino project.  Any help is very welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Eric, could you explain why this is a [robotics.se] question, and not a question for [arduino.se]?

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with SparkFun, here are some fairly east to use, fairly cheep parts that can help accomplish what I believe you are trying to do.

It would appear as if triggering the camera is a simple as a digital pulse from the Arduino - next step is to figure out when to make that pulse.

If you are looking to build a remote control device, might I suggest something as simple as SF's 434MHz transmitter / receiver pair?

[Transmitter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10534)
[Receiver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10532)

The transmitter would be your remote control device, which would send a broadcast on button press. The receiver on the camera wold pick up this broadcast, and trigger the camera.

Now these modules are serial communication, so you would need an Arduino on the remote to command the transmitter - but you could easily build your own small remote for pretty cheap if you opt to buy just an [ATMEGA328](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9061), the processor of the Arduino.